# Rails 4, How to add an s3 image to wicked pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, amazon-s3

In rails 4, I am using `wicked_pdf` gem for `.pdf` file download. I have to add an image inside this pdf, right now image is rendering through `wicked_pdf_image_tag` in development but in test environment image(s3) is not rendering.

Used Gems are,

```
gem 'wicked_pdf', '1.0.3'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary', '0.9.9.3'
```

In initializers,

```
class WickedPdf
  wkhtmltopdf_path = Rails.env.production? ? "#{Rails.root}/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64" : "#{Rails.root}/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64"
  WICKED_PDF = {
   :exe_path => wkhtmltopdf_path,
   :wkhtmltopdf => wkhtmltopdf_path
  }
end
```

In controller,

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {
    render :pdf => "sample",
    :margin => {:top => 10, :bottom => 10, :left => 10, :right => 10},
    :orientation => 'Portrait', # default , Landscape,
    :no_background => true
  }
end
```

In views, I have tried to load through

```
<%= Rails.env.development? ? wicked_pdf_image_tag("img/logo.png") : wicked_pdf_image_tag("#{Rails.root}/public/assets/img/logo.png") %>

<%= Rails.env.development? ? wicked_pdf_image_tag("img/logo.png") : wicked_pdf_image_tag("#{Rails.root}/assets/img/logo.png") %>

<%= image_tag(ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('img/logo.png')) %>
```

How can I load `s3` image in pdf file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the image in a s3 bucket and make it public. After that try it like below. If you use the below code no need to use separate syntax for different environments, it will works for all .Hope it works.

```
<%= wicked_pdf_image_tag('//s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/image.png') %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have worked on the similar functionality but using **PDFKit** gem. But I think rendering logic will be almost similar.

Below is the code where I rendered my partial in controller

```
def print_batch
  batch = Batch.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf {
      html = render_to_string("_batch",:formats => [:html], layout: false , locals: { batch: batch })
      Rails.logger.debug(html.inspect)
      kit = PDFKit.new(html)
      send_data(kit.to_pdf, :filename => "file_name_#{batch.id}.pdf", :type => 'application/pdf') and return
    }
    format.html
    format.json { render json: {id: batch.id, processed: batch.processed?} }
  end     

end
```

In **_batch.html.haml**. You can see I have used **person.s3_logo** for rendering the pdf image.

```
  - logo_image_pdf = person.logo.present? ? person.s3_logo : default_credit_logo 
  - logo_image_html = person.logo.present? ? image_path(Person.logo.thumb('100x100').url) : image_path('default_credit_logo.png')
  - logo_image = params[:format] == 'pdf' ? logo_image_pdf : logo_image_html

  .bucks           
    %img.logo{src: logo_image }
```

In **Person.rb** model. Anyway we cannot directly render image in PDF file directly from s3. So any gem will first download it in /tmp folder and render it. This is how I have done it in my model file.

```
  def s3_logo
    file = open(self.logo.remote_url)
    file.path if file
  end
```