# Convert a PDF view with Wicked_pdf to a file and saving it to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5, wicked-pdf

I currently have a model with a specific controller method that renders PDF view.

Let's say this model is `photographer_quote` I have a method called `print_quote` inside the `photographer_quote` controller that does this job.

Here is the code :

```
      @quote= Photographer_quote.find(params[:id])
      respond_to do |format|
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: 'quote'+@quote.id.to_s
      end
```

Everything is fine, when a link targeting this very controller method is actionned, it created the PDF on the fly and renders it inside browser. (of course I have a view with all the formatting ...)

Though, now I would like to put this PDF creation into a queue (Sidekiq) and save it as a PDF file into another model (lets call it `PDF_quotes`) which has a single PDF Paperclip attachment.

Though I am struggling to have the PDF saved on S3 through Paperclip.

Wicked pdf mentions this :

```
# or from your controller, using views & templates and all wicked_pdf options as normal
pdf = render_to_string pdf: "some_file_name", template: "templates/pdf", encoding: "UTF-8"

# then save to a file
save_path = Rails.root.join('pdfs','filename.pdf')
File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
  file << pdf
end
```

Do I have to create the file locally first place ? And how can I write the file onto model `PDF_quotes` with a Paperclip attachment named `quote`

Comment: did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38604090/rails-4-how-to-add-an-s3-image-to-wicked-pdf#38606082

Comment: In your thread, the person is trying to add an image located on S3 into their PDF

Comment: But actually I will try different things today and see if it works. I think I don't need to save locally  before sending to S3

Comment: I configured something similar for carrierwave https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#using-amazon-s3 I come back if I have any idea keep my posted thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will get you going in the right direction, with regard to:

"Do I have to create the file locally first place ? And how can I write the file onto model PDF_quotes with a Paperclip attachment named quote"

You can create a WickedPdf in memory and pipe directly to a Paperclip model like this.

The model PDF_quote has the standard Paperclip "has_attached_file :quote"

In the controller for example you can do this:

```
        # Generate PDF
        pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
          render_to_string('your-pdf-template-in-html.pdf') # This is a view
        )

        # Stream PDF from WickedPdf to Paperclip PDF_quote.quote
        # Content Type is automatically read by Paperclip (at least for application/pdf in my testing)
        pdf_quote = PDF_quote.new(
          # Other attributes here as well.....
          quote: StringIO.new(pdf) # Pipe pdf to quote
        )
        pdf_quote.quote_file_name = "your_quote_file_name.pdf"
        pdf_quote.save
```

There are more options you can add to .pdf_from_string please see the Paperclip GitHub. Things like layouts, footers, headers, etc...

I hope this helps!

Comment: PDF_quote is a polymorphic os I have had to tweak a bit, but your answer is perfect. Thank you